# How to loop multiple elements in python selenium (different CSS selectors)

Tags: python, html, selenium, loops, web-scraping

I am trying to loop inside a class `offer-list-wrapper` which has multiple elements inside, almost all the elements are common in the web page for search A and search B (I am scraping a crawler).

As you can see in both images, `offer-list-wrapper` is a common element.

I want to extract the data that is inside every `organic-offer-wrapper organic-gallery-offer-inner` and `organic-list-offer-inner m-gallery-product-item-v2`  classes. Which is very easy to do if you loop inside them with a CSS selector like this:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.organic-list-offer-inner.m-gallery-product-item-v2'):
```

In that way you can get every element inside them.

[image]

[image]

BUT the issue starts here: I need to loop inside both cases with ONE generic code that loop inside both classes, and in case a new class appears it has to loop inside it.

Let me show you my code:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('offer-list-wrapper'):
    try:
        item_name = element.find_element_by_class_name('organic-gallery-title__content').text
    except:
        item_name = np.nan
    try:
        price = element.find_element_by_class_name('gallery-offer-price').get_attribute('title').replace('$', '').replace(',', '')
        min_order = element.find_element_by_class_name('gallery-offer-minorder').find_element_by_tag_name('span').text.replace(' Pieces', '').replace(' Piece', '').replace(' Units', '').replace(' Unit', '').replace(' Sets', '').replace(' Set', '').replace(' Pairs', '').replace(' Pair', '').replace('Boxes', '').replace('Box', '').replace('Bags', '').replace('Bag', '')     
        # separate min and max price
    except:
        price = np.nan
        min_order = np.nan
```

This first one returns only the first element:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.organic-offer-wrapper.organic-gallery-offer-inner'):
    try:
        item_name = element.find_element_by_class_name('organic-gallery-title__content').text
    except:
        item_name = np.nan
    try:
        price = element.find_element_by_class_name('gallery-offer-price').get_attribute('title').replace('$', '').replace(',', '')
        min_order = element.find_element_by_class_name('gallery-offer-minorder').find_element_by_tag_name('span').text.replace(' Pieces', '').replace(' Piece', '').replace(' Units', '').replace(' Unit', '').replace(' Sets', '').replace(' Set', '').replace(' Pairs', '').replace(' Pair', '').replace('Boxes', '').replace('Box', '').replace('Bags', '').replace('Bag', '')     
        # separate min and max price
    except:
        price = np.nan
        min_order = np.nan
```

This second one only loops inside `.organic-offer-wrapper.organic-gallery-offer-inner` (returning all elements that I need), but it doesn't loop inside `.organic-list-offer-inner.m-gallery-product-item-v2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the products by searching for the div tags that contain the attribute **data-content="productItem"**. That is assuming each item has that attribute. From the screenshots you posted, it seems like that is the case.

You can accomplish this using find_elements_by_xpath()

```
for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-content="productItem"]'):
    ....
```

This would probably be the best way without having to worry about the elements having different css classes.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. In my code I used the word element instead for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-content="productItem"]'): THANK YOU for your help! :)